# Should I destruct an array to compare it with the first index of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have a task on Codecademy to create a function that takes an array of arrays and compares the first index of each array to another array with 4 indexes.
Basically, I have a group of credit card numbers and I am looking at the first digit of each number and returning the company that sent the card based on the first number.

I chose to destruct the array like this

```
const cardCompanies = [3,4,5,6] = ['Amex','Visa','Mastercard','Discover']
```

While comparing them with these

```
[ [ 3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6 ],
  [ 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5 ],
  [ 5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3 ],
  [ 3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4 ],
  [ 6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5 ],
  [ 5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4 ],
  [ 3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4 ],
  [ 6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3 ],
  [ 4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3 ] ]
```

The function, in the end, is supposed to return either the card company or 'Company not found'.

Thank you ahead of time for all advice. I enjoy working through this kind of problem.

Comment: It is invalid `const cardCompanies = [3,4,5,6] = ['Amex','Visa','Mastercard','Discover']`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I think your first line should be `const cardCompanies = { 3: 'Amex', 4: 'Visa', 5: 'Mastercard', 6: 'Discover' };`.  So `cardCompanies[6]` would be "Discover".  You should post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: could you share the sample input & output?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to store `cardCompanies` data in an `object` so that we can access in `O(1)`

```js
const cardCompanies = {
  "3": "Amex",
  "4": "Visa",
  "5": "MasterCard",
  "6": "Discover",
};

const testArray = [
  [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6],
  [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5],
  [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3],
  [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4],
  [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5],
  [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4],
  [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4],
  [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3],
  [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3],
];

testArray.forEach((arr) => {
  const [cardFirstDigit] = arr;
  
  if (cardCompanies[cardFirstDigit]) {
    console.log(cardCompanies[cardFirstDigit]);
  } else {
    console.log("Company not found");
  }
});
```